# Como validar o defaultPrevented = false no meu teste angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("app")

.service('EventHandler', EventHandler);

EventHandler.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$animate', '$state', '$stateParams', '$sanitize', '$q', '$uibModal', 'toastr',
'storage', 'StorageService', 'LogService', 'LanguageResource', 'LoginService', 'StcpUtilsService', 'DAOService',
'CSRF', 'Authorization', 'ShortcutService', 'data_login', 'PermissionsService', 'BusinessLogicService', 'DebugMode'
]; 

function EventHandler($rootScope, $location, $animate, $state, $stateParams, $sanitize, $q, $uibModal, toastr, storage, StorageService,
                  LogService, LanguageResource, LoginService, StcpUtilsService, DAOService, CSRF,
                  Authorization, ShortcutService, data_login, PermissionsService, BusinessLogicService, Debug) {

var animate;
/* = parameters.$animate || $animate; */
var rootScope;
/* = parameters.$rootScope || $rootScope; */
var scope;
/* = parameters.$scope; */
var _toastr;
/* = parameters.toastr || toastr; */
var _storage;
/* = parameters.StorageService || StorageService; */
var location;
/* = parameters.$location || $location; */
var log;
/* = parameters.LogService ? parameters.LogService.log : LogService.log || LogService.log; */
var language;
/* = parameters.LanguageResource || LanguageResource; */
var shortcut;
var t;
var dao;
var DebugMode;

return {
    initialize: initialize_component,
    onCheckSession: onCheckSessionHandle,
    onLogin: onLoginHandle,
    onLogout: onLogoutHandle,
    onStateChangeError: onStateChangeErrorHandle,
    onHideMenuCheck: onHideMenuCheckHandle,
    onSetInstance: onSetInstanceHandle,
    onRemoveInstance: onRemoveInstanceHandle,
    onGetInstanceName: onGetInstanceNameHandle,
    onGetInstanceId: onGetInstanceIdHandle,
    onGetOperatorLogged: onGetOperatorLoggedHandle,
    onOperatorIsLogged: onOperatorIsLoggedHandle,
    onShakeMenu: onShakeMenuHandle,
    onCheckInstance: onCheckInstanceHandle,
    onSave: onSaveHandle,
    onDelete: onDeleteHandle,
    onInterceptError: onInterceptErrorHandle,
    onChangeOperatorPassword: onChangePasswordHandle,
    onGetTransfer: onGetTransferHandle,
    onOpenChangeModuleDialog: onOpenChangeModuleDialogHandle,
    onChangeSubModule: onChangeSubModuleHandle,
    onDisplaySelectionInstance: onDisplaySelectionInstanceHandle,
    onGetInstances: onGetInstancesHandle,
    onCheckModule: onCheckModuleHandle,
    // onDataToPersist: onDataToPersistHandle
};

// function onDataToPersistHandle() { rootScope.$on('dataToPersist', onDataToPersist); }

function onRemoveInstanceHandle() {
    rootScope.$on('removeInstance', onRemoveInstance);
}        

function onCheckSessionHandle() {
        rootScope.$on('checkSession', onCheckSession);
}

function onRemoveInstance(ev, args) {
    onCheckSession(ev, args);

    if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
        _storage[storage].del("instance_id");
        _storage[storage].del("instance_name");
        _storage.local.del("instance_name");
        _storage.local.del("instanceSelected");
        _storage.session.del("instanceSelected");
        rootScope.instanceSelected = undefined;
        delete rootScope.displaySelectionInstance;
        delete rootScope.instance_id;
        delete rootScope.instance_name;
    }
} 

  function onCheckSession(ev, args) {
        var serv;
        var opLogged;
        var head_req;
        var perm;
        var userLog;
        var token;
        var current_module;

        try {
            serv = StorageService[storage];
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
        try {
            opLogged = serv.get('operator_logged') || null;
        } catch (e) {
            opLogged = null;
        }
        try {
            head_req = serv.get('header_request') || null;
        } catch (e) {
            head_req = null;
        }
        try {
            perm = serv.get('permissions') || null;
        } catch (e) {
            perm = null;
        }
        try {
            userLog = serv.get('userLogged') || null;
        } catch (e) {
            userLog = null;
        }
        try {
            token = serv.get('token_info') || null;
        } catch (e) {
            token = null;
        }
        try {
            current_module = serv.get('current_module');
        } catch (e) {
            current_module = null;
        }

        if (token === null || opLogged === null || head_req === null || perm === null || userLog === null) {
            if (LoginService.doLogout()) {
                // Previne que o listener passado por parâmetro seja executado.
                ev.preventDefault();
                // Previne que os demais listeners assinados ao evento passado sejam executados.
                ev.stopPropagation();
                // Retira do escopo raiz dados do operador logado.
                $rootScope.operator_logged = undefined;
                // Inibe a exibição do Menu principal.
                $rootScope.hideMenu = true;
                // Se não estiver no estado de login.
                Eif (!$state.is('login') && !$state.is('master.modules')) {
                    // Exibe mensagem de sessão expirada.
                    _toastr.warning(t('Sessão expirada, inicie uma nova sessão!'), t("Sessão expirada!"));
                    $state.go("login", {location: "replace"});
                } else if (!$state.is('login')) {
                    // Redireciona para o estado de login.
                    $state.go("login", {location: "replace"});
                }
            }
        }
    }

//...
```

E estou aplicando o seguinte teste com intuito de validar o ev.defaultPrevented = false para que possa entrar dentro do if

```
  it('testing if the onRemoveInstance function', function(){ 
    var args;
    var ev = {
        defaultPrevented: false 
    };

    function onRemoveInstance(ev) {
        if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
            srv.onRemoveInstance();
            rootScope.$emit('removeInstance');
        }
    }
    onRemoveInstance(ev);

    Array.prototype.removeByAttr = srv.onCheckSession(ev, args);       
});
```

Porém não esta entrando dentro do if. Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado e qual a maneira correta para o teste dar certo.

Comment: creio que onCheckSession está modificando o valor de ev

Comment: @FelipeDuarte sabe como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: basta verificar o retorno da função onCheckSession, e o que causa essa mundança, se quizer edite o código com a mesma

Comment: @FelipeDuarte foi editado

Comment: Bom como pude ver onCheckSession está referênciando onCheckSessionHandle, não sei se você tem acesso a essa função pois seu projeto está bem modularizado, retire onCheckSession(ev, args); do método onRemoveInstance, creio que irá entrar no if, ai é só arrumar onCheckSession posteriormente.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte sabe como faço pra remover esse onCheckSession dentro da minha iteração de teste?

Comment: Vou tentar responder mas seu problema não é algo fácil de entender

Answer (score 1):

`Default prevented` foi definido aqui (lembrando que esse evento só funciona efetivamente em objeto `DOM`)

```
srv.ev = {
            defaultPrevented: false   
        }
```

Ao chamar `onRemoveInstance`, `onCheckSession` está modificando `ev`, portanto `ev.defaultPrevented` não será mais falso.

```
function onRemoveInstance(ev, args) {
    onCheckSession(ev, args); <--------

    if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
        _storage[storage].del("instance_id");
        _storage[storage].del("instance_name");
        _storage.local.del("instance_name");
        _storage.local.del("instanceSelected");
        _storage.session.del("instanceSelected");
        rootScope.instanceSelected = undefined;
        delete rootScope.displaySelectionInstance;
        delete rootScope.instance_id;
        delete rootScope.instance_name;
    }
}
```

Em um exemplo simples

```js
var ev = {
  defaultPrevented: false 
};

function onRemoveInstance(ev) {
  if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
   alert('entrou');
  }
}

onRemoveInstance(ev);
```

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer. Em relação ao meu teste o que vinha fazendo vai ser inútil na tentativa de entrar no if. Teria como eu fazer dentro do meu teste um mock de uma instância para remover esse onCheckSession que está modificando minha função? E como fazer isso ?

Comment: defaultPrevented verifica se um elemento no dom está em estado preventivo certo? na função onCheckSession existe um if com o seguinte ev.preventDefault(); ou seja para estar dando false, foi-se necessário entrar nesse if, ai está a raiz do problema, não sei como ele entrou, pois não se trata de um objeto DOM, mas não sei como funciona pois nunca fiz testes preventivos, enfim para que não entre no if, ev.preventDefault(); não pode ser setado